# Update list of values in a dictionary (cumulative update)

Tags: python, dictionary

Context: I have a dictionary with some soccer results and I'd like to create a second dictionary displaying the values as a list with the soccer match results.

For example, I have this initial dictionary:

```
dict_results = {('FCP', 'SLB'): (1, 4),
 ('FCP', 'SCP'): (2, 5),
 ('SLB', 'FCP'): (2, 6),
 ('SLB', 'SCP'): (1, 5),
 ('SCP', 'FCP'): (2, 4),
 ('SCP', 'SLB'): (1, 4)}
```

and I'd like to get this format:

```
tabela = {'FCP': [win, draw, loss, scored_goals, suff_goals, points],
 'SLB': [win, draw, loss, scored_goals, suff_goals, points],
 'SCP': [win, draw, loss, scored_goals, suff_goals, points]}
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
tabela = {}

for teams,goals in dict_results.items():
    win = 0
    draw = 0
    loss = 0
    scored_goals = 0
    suff_goals = 0
    points = 0

    print(teams,goals)
    if teams[0] not in tabela:
        tabela[teams[0]] = [win, draw, loss, scored_goals, suff_goals, points]
    

    if goals[0] > goals[1]:
        #teams[0] update
        win = 1
        scored_goals = goals[0]
        suff_goals = goals[1]
        points = 3
        tabela[teams[0]].update([win,draw,loss,scored_goals,suff_goals,points])
    elif goals[0] == goals[1]:
        draw = 1
        scored_goals = goals[0]
        suff_goals = goals[1]
        points = 1
        tabela[teams[0]].update([win,draw,loss,scored_goals,suff_goals,points])
        tabela[teams[1]].update([win,draw,loss,scored_goals,suff_goals,points])
    elif goals[0] < goals[1]:
        ...
```

but the values are kept at 0 (they don't actually update) which makes sense really since every iteration I'm basically "resetting" the values and even if the values were being updated the way I'm trying to do, I wouldn't really get cumulative values.

How could I do it so that I can compare the goals for each team and update the results accordingly? For example, in the tuple ('FCP','SLB') the goals scored for 'FCP' were 1 and goals scored for SLB were 4, which means that 'FCP' suffered 4 goals, scored 1 goal, got no points, increased the loss by 1 and 'SLB' increase the win by 1, suffered 1 goal, scored 4 goals and got 3 points (without using dictionary or list comprehensions)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you dont want to use comprehensiobs?

Comment: I'm still a beginner in python and I'd like to fully understand the basics using loops instead

Comment: I think you should be using `tablea[teams[i]] = [win,draw,loss,...]` rather than `.update`. To use `.update` you need to pass a dictionary. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp

Comment: That's a good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an addition, you are looping over both teams but you are recording only the result for team one. You can get both teams with an extra for loop.

```py
tabela = {}

for teams,goals in dict_results.items():
    for iter in range(len(teams)):
        team = teams[iter]
        win = 0
        draw = 0
        loss = 0
        scored_goals = 0
        suff_goals = 0
        points = 0
        
        if iter == 0:
            n = 0
            m = 1
        else:
            n = 1
            m = 0

        if team not in tabela:
            tabela[team] = [win, draw, loss, scored_goals, suff_goals, points]
        
        if goals[n] > goals[m]:
            win, draw, loss, scored_goals, suff_goals, points = tabela[team]
            win += 1
            scored_goals += goals[n]
            suff_goals += goals[m]
            points += 3
            tabela[team] = [win,draw,loss,scored_goals,suff_goals,points]
        elif goals[n] < goals[m]:
            win, draw, loss, scored_goals, suff_goals, points = tabela[team]
            win += 0
            scored_goals += goals[n]
            suff_goals += goals[m]
            points += 0
            tabela[team] = [win,draw,loss,scored_goals,suff_goals,points]
        elif goals[n] == goals[m]:
            win, draw, loss, scored_goals, suff_goals, points = tabela[team]
            win += 0
            scored_goals += goals[n]
            suff_goals += goals[m]
            points += 1
            tabela[team] = [win,draw,loss,scored_goals,suff_goals,points]
        

print(tabela)

 >>{'FCP': [2, 0, 0, 13, 13, 6], 'SLB': [2, 0, 0, 11, 13, 6], 'SCP': [2, 0, 0, 13, 11, 6]}
```

Depending on your iteration `iter`, `n` and `m` switch numbers. This way the if statement checks the scores for team one on iteration 1 and the scores for team two on iteration 2.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it looks like you are indeed "resetting" the values on every iteration. In Python, the `.update` function doesn't add values, it just replaces the dictionary entry. You can still use `tabela[team].update`, you just need to add to the previous value yourself.

Here's a code example of how to do that:

```py
    ...
    if goals[0] > goals[1]:
        #teams[0] update
        win, draw, loss, scored_goals, suff_goals, points = tabela[teams[0]]
        win += 1
        scored_goals += goals[0]
        suff_goals += goals[1]
        points += 3
        tabela[teams[0]].update([win,draw,loss,scored_goals,suff_goals,points])
    elif goals[0] == goals[1]:
        ...
    elif goals[0] < goals[1]:
        ...
```